# ¿Cómo ignoro un elemento superpuesto?

Tags: html, css, click, hover, position

Me surgió un pequeño problema, como se aprecia en el siguiente código:

```css
.rojo, .azul {
    color: black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    user-select: none;
}

.rojo {
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.7);
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.azul {
    background-color: blue;
    left: 150px;
    top: 150px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="rojo">Rojo</div>
<div class="azul">Azul</div>
```

Tengo acomodados dos elementos, de los cuales la caja roja se superpone por encima de la caja azul, y justamente así es como los quiero... pero a la hora de hacer hover o querer hacer click en la caja azul, la caja roja no me lo permite. ¿Entonces cómo puedo acomodar así a los elementos, pero ignorando a la caja roja?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías usar la propiedad **CSS** `pointer-events: none;` en tu elemento `.rojo`. De esa manera, al tener los eventos del ratón desactivados en el elemento `.rojo` conseguiremos que comiencen a escucharse lo del elemento `.azul`, aun teniendo el ratón encima del elemento `.rojo` (que es el que se superpone).

En mi ejemplo puede verse que se activa el evento `hover` de `.azul` cuando realmente estamos encima del elemento `.rojo`. (por estar en la zona en la que ambos coinciden y estar `.rojo` por encima de `.azul`).

```css
.rojo, .azul {
    color: black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    user-select: none;
}

.rojo {
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.7);
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.azul {
    background-color: blue;
    left: 150px;
    top: 150px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.azul:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="rojo">Rojo</div>
<div class="azul">Azul</div>
```

Comment: Justamente era lo que acababa de investigar, muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Una forma podría ser cambiar el z-index al hacer hover:

```
.azul:hover {
   z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Si haces eso el azul se superpondría. Debes dejar que el evento se propague y atraparlo en el azul, o eventualmente, atraparlo en la roja y en el código del controlador de evento identificar si ocurre en la zona superpuesta. En caso de estar en ella invocar desde ahí el evento correspondiente para la zona azul (algo así como pasarlo)